# Cloud Composer Airflow webserver 502 Server Error after "successfully" updating with PyPi packages

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I receive this error soon after upating Cloud Composer with PyPi packages - occurs consistently across the 4 configurations outlined below

**python packages added to Cloud Composer**

forex_python>=1.5.0

datalab>=1.1.5

**Airflow webserver error**

502 Server Error

Error: Server Error

The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.

**GCP status over period status.cloud.google.com - no issues with any of:**

Google Cloud Composer

Google Kubernetes Engine

**Sample of StackDriver errors found**

severity: "ERROR"  textPayload: "worker: Warm shutdown (MainProcess)

severity: "ERROR"  textPayload: "INFO:googleapiclient.discovery:URL being requested: POST https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/projects/FAKE_PROJECT/topics/europe-west2-FAKE_INSTANCE-composer-agent-to-backend-topic-FAKE_TOPIC:publish?alt=json

severity: "ERROR"  textPayload: "Fetching cluster endpoint and auth data.

severity: "ERROR"  textPayload: "kubeconfig entry generated for europe-west2-FAKE_INSTANCE-gke.

severity: "ERROR"   textPayload: "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/configuration.py:569: DeprecationWarning: Specifying both AIRFLOW_HOME environment variable and airflow_home in the config file is deprecated. Please use only the AIRFLOW_HOME environment variable and remove the config file entry.

***Initial Issue***

Env 1) created via Cloud Composer GUI

-created composer env X1 same specs as 2) below

-added 2 python packages listed above

-DAGS added and were working until 6-dec-2019

-around 6-dec-2019 Airflow webserver error -> result is environment unusable

***Further Testing***

**CREATE STEP**

Env 2)

```
gcloud beta composer environments create ${COMPOSER_NAME} \
    --location=${COMPOSER_LOCATION} \
    --image-version=composer-1.8.2-airflow-1.10.3 \
    --disk-size=100GB \
    --python-version=3 \
    --node-count=3
```

Env 3)

```
gcloud composer environments create ${COMPOSER_NAME} \
    --location=${COMPOSER_LOCATION} \
    --image-version=composer-1.8.1-airflow-1.10.3 \
    --disk-size=100GB \
    --python-version=3 \
    --node-count=3
```

Env 4) manually created composer env X2 same config as 2)

**All Successful according to gcloud CLI and Cloud Composer GUI**

**PY PACAKGES STEP**

Update 2) and 3) using...

```
gcloud composer environments update ${COMPOSER_NAME} \
    --location ${COMPOSER_LOCATION} \
    --update-pypi-packages-from-file=PyPi_req.txt
```

Update 4) using Cloud Composer GUI

***All Successful according to gcloud CLI and Cloud Composer GUI***

***BUT All have the Airflow webserver error -> result is environment unusable***

Has anyone observed and resolved this issue?

Comment: Removed forex_python package and problem disappears

Determined that forex_python requires requests

https://forex-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

However that should be fine because based on following doco, requests is built-in
 
https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/versioning/composer-versions
requests==2.19.1

Given it takes up to 50 minutes for each update of Cloud Composer, a bit of a concern that when adding multiple packages, the service indicates success and StackDriver logs do not identify which package is problematic nor why.

Comment: When this happened with a pandas PyPI I've added, the logging showed that the version I tried to install wasn't compatible with the Airflow instance (and therefore couldn't be initialized). When I changed to a compatible version, the error disappeared and the Airflow went back running.

Answer (score 2):

It's great to hear that the issue is solved, just to compliment your earlier comment:

It is important to note that The Airflow webserver is an add-on. Even when it is down, Airflow can still run normally, if nothing else is broken in the Composer environment. Based on this, if your Airflow webserver is being affected, you could use the [Airflow CLI](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/composer/environments/run)  (via gcloud).

I also suggest you look at this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/troubleshooting-dags#dag_crashes_the_airflow_web_server_or_causes_it_to_return_a_502_gateway_timeout_error) where you will find useful documentation about how to manage this kind of issues and the causes that could provoke it.

Regarding the concern about the time that takes to update your Composer environment please note that Composer needs to create a lot of resources, I suggest you look in the [architecture of the Composer environment](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/overview#architecture) where you will find all the components that needs to be updated which each change.

Comment: Thanks Enrique, part of the advantage of Airflow is fantastic GUI/visualizations so CLI is not much consolation. The middle link you provided references dags but this issue is before dags are added to env. I understand the components - it's more the double-hit of slow upate AND lack of useful diagnostic feedback in this case. Cheers.